# How to direct users from the landing iFrame to another iFrame?

Tags: iframe, fbml

I want to customize the Facebook Page for the organization I'm working for. I would like to have a custom landing page as an iFrame with "Like our page!". Done that. But when the users become fans, they are directed to the Wall next time they visit the page. How can I make Facebook direct them to another iFrame? It was possible with FBML to create a custom landing page and then direct users to a custom fan page, but now I can't seem to find the solution for this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this can't be done. Facebook Page settings dictate that you can only define the page non-fans land on.

Comment: So all fans are "doomed" to land on the wall next time they visit the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I too have wanted this functionality for a while but no sign of it yet.